# swaks failing on ipv6 despite forcing it to use ipv4 with -4 switch

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, email

```
swaks -4 -S -t user1@example1.com -f user2@example2.com -ao -au user2 -ap ***** -tls -s  example3  --header Subject: Q4mSShEEoYnAviWg
*** Error connecting to example3:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET6: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I'm using `-4` option, so why does it complain about `ipv6` hostname?

Answer (score 3):

`IO::Socket::INET6` is a Perl module providing that script's network sockets.  `INET6` added IPv6 support to the `INET` module, and is fully capable of IPv4.

Find this system's DNS servers and test them directly with a different utility:

```
dig example3 A
```

Determine and fix why you cannot connect to DNS.